# Browse an Xarray VB6 from True DBGrid

Tags: vb6

I'm ceating an application with VB6.I created an XArray "X_list" which the number of rows is dynamic.My problem is how can i browse this XArray and get the value of the element in the column "j" and row "i"

Comment: here's the declaration of My X_List Dim x_liste As New XArrayDB

Comment: That explains nothing. What's an XArrayDB?

Comment: XArrayDB belongs to True DBGrid : http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/default.htm#!xarraydbobject.htm

Comment: Yes, that's it. I want to find the dimension of my XArray DB
   For i = 0 To x_liste.????
           x_liste_examen.Value(i, 4) = ListeExamen.Columns(4)
           somme = somme + x_liste_examen.Value(i, 4)
            lblmontanttotal.Caption = somme
       Next i

Comment: Use LowerBound and UpperBound. See [docs](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/default.htm#!lowerboundpropertyxarraydb.htm). Can I also suggest you should probably read the TDBGrid and XArrayDB documentation - it is excellent. For instance work through the [tutorial on XArrayDBs and TDBGrid](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/default.htm#!tutorial19displayingarraydatainunboundstoragemode.htm). For one thing it answers your question here.